# Selenium/ChromeDriver Timeout Exception when Webscraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have built a webscraper that scrapes urls. Its occassionally having an issue (doesn't occur all the time). I get a `TimeOutException` at this particular part of my code:

```
tries = 0
while tries<1000:
    try:  
        domain=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cite._Rm")))
        domain = domain.text
        break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            tries+=1
            self.browser.refresh()
```

Error:

> File "", line 389, in findDomains
>       domain=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cite._Rm")))   File "", line 78, in until
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: The code you show in your question won't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have it wrapped in a while block with multiple attempts, just handle `TimeoutException`:

```
try:  
    domain=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cite._Rm")))
    domain = domain.text
    break
except (StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException):
    tries+=1
    self.browser.refresh()
```

Note that it's difficult to say more without being able to reproduce the problem, or at least having a link to the target webpage that have occasional issues you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

You get timeout exception because element was not found during timeout, try to increase it or refresh page like in a code below

```
tries = 0
while tries<1000:
    try:  
        domain=WebdriverWait(self.browser, timeout=10).until(
             EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cite._Rm"))
        )
        domain_text = domain.text
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        tries+=1
        self.browser.refresh()
```